# Задача: вывод сообщения каждую минуту, использование DateTime

Tags: c#

Придумал себе задачу: вывод некоторого сообщения каждую минуту. Данный код сообщение выводит, но далеко не один раз. Такого быть не должно, сообщение должно выводится только один раз. Искренне не понимаю ошибку.

```
DateTime fixDate = DateTime.Now;
        int checkPoint = fixDate.Second;
        bool key = false;
        Console.WriteLine($"Секунды при запуске {checkPoint}");
        for (; ; )
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

            if ((checkPoint == now.Second) && (key = true))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Прошла минута");
                key = false;
            }
            if (checkPoint != now.Second)
            {
                key = true;
            }
        }
```

Фиксирую дату, сохраняю себе секунду запуска программы. Начинаю постоянно обновлять дату, если секунда равна чекпоинту и флаг истинен, то вывожу сообщение. Флаг обновляется и становится истинным только тогда, если секунда не равна чекпоинту. Отсюда совсем не понятно, как сообщение может выводится, если флаг может стать истинным только в том случае, если секунда чекпоинту не равна. Пытался юзать отладку, но из-за работы со временем сообщение не выводится никогда, так как флаг всегда ложный. Как правильно доработать алгоритм, чтобы сообщение выводилось только один раз каждую минуту?

Comment: `(key = true)` - это так и задумано? присвоить в проверке?

Comment: Не баг а фича. Крайне благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    DateTime nextMinute = fixDate.AddMinutes(1);
    while(true) 
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        if (now >= nextMinute)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Прошла минута");
            nextMinute = nextMinute.AddMinutes(1);
        }
    }
```